# Dalvik/2.1.0 in Android's version more than 5

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, dalvik

I installed [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en_US) on my android and did some scans because [this topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203715/phone-sending-many-packets). So, I saw Dalvik/2.1.0 in a log of WhatsApp on port 80. Since Dalvik/2.1.0 should be prior that Android 5, is it normal I saw this on my LG X Power that has Android 6.0.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I wouldn't worry about the Dalvik version number**

Searching on `Dalvik/2.1.0` leads to http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/plugin294709/dalvik which lists the user agent string used by older Android devices.

Note that the numbering went up from `Dalvik/1.6.0` on Android 4.4.4 to `Dalvik/2.1.0` on Android 5.0 and up. Another posting at https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/issues/667 indicates that at least through Android 7.1.1 still used the `2.1.0` version.

From this StackOverflow post on [Browser sending “Dalvik” as user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23804278/295004) it looks like the VM is sending the user agent string.

Most likely, the version number changed at Android 5.0 Lollipop when [ART](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik) became the default runtime.